# Android Studio Change Occurrence Color

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio

How can I change the occurrence/write occurrence color in Android Studio? Is this even possible? In Eclipse it was found (on a Mac) under Preferences->General->Editors->Text Editors->Annotations

Does Android Studio even provide this option? It's a number of small annoyances like this (as well as the massive performance issues it seems to be having thus far) that prevent me from moving to Android Studio.

Currently running Android Studio 1.2 Beta if that helps.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Go to menu

> Preferences > Editor > Color&Fonts > General

Find "Identifier under caret" and change Foregound or/and Background colors with a color you wish. When you click a variable, it will be highlighted with the color you chose.

Answer (score 1):

To mark selected occurrences in Android Studio you have to additionally use a shortcut

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>

to mark them. Then all occurrences will be highlighted with darker better to see color. That option is also available in menu

Edit -> Find -> Select All Occurrences

Still if you want to change that color then you can find it in

File -> Settings -> Editor -> Colors & Fonts -> General -> Selection background

If you are using default scheme then you will have to save a new scheme to change selection background color.

Sadly I didn't find any option to change the color of selected occurrence after selecting class/variable (one click, like in Eclipse). I guess that there is no option for that yet.